# Send full URL to backend server with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'd like to have Nginx act as a reverse proxy for a backend service, *but* the connection to the backend service must itself go through another proxy:

```
 [nginx] -> [HTTP proxy] -> [backend service]
```

It does not appear that Nginx has a way to configure that the outgoing connection passes through a proxy (e.g., the `http_proxy` environment variable is ignored).

But it might be sufficient to:

1. Set the `proxy_pass` destination to the HTTP proxy server address.
2. Convince Nginx send the complete target URL to the proxy as in `GET http://backend/path/etc` instead of just `GET /path/etc`.

I tried:

```
rewrite ^/prefix/(.*) http://backend/$1 break;
proxy_pass http://proxy;
```

which *almost* works, but the behavior of [`rewrite`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) is that it stops processing and issues a redirect if the replacement begins with `http://`. ([Code here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/0a90893da03517a17562feb69b170af0365b2068/src/http/modules/ngx_http_rewrite_module.c#L354-L361)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hacky way to work around the redirecting behavior of `rewrite` by using two `rewrite` directives:

```
location /prefix/ {
    rewrite ^/prefix/(.*) xxx://backend/$1 ;
    rewrite ^xxx(.*) http$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://proxy;
}
```

An incoming GET request to `http://frontend/prefix/x` would therefore cause a connection to the proxy server and send `GET http://backend/x` which would be forwarded to the backend server as `GET /x`.